# How come my view block is not loading using ajax?

Tags: views, 8, javascript, ajax

We have a view, `myview`, that has an exposed filter `title` (text input). The view has `Exposed form in block:Yes` and so we load it onto the page under `admin/structure/block`. The block has a machine name of `exposedform_myview_title`.

We want to remove it from display and only load the view block on click of an icon. How come my view block is not loading when using ajax?

View Setup:

- view_name = 'myview`
- when creating view, view page setting -> "create a page" was set to true
- view machine name = `mypage`
- view `use ajax` = Yes
- view block (displayed using admin/structure/block) machine name `exposedform_myview`

**Error message**

> https://somesite/path/views/ajax?view_name=myview&view_block_id=mypage
>   404 (not found)

**myjs.js**

This will load the view itself and not the `exposedform_myview_title` block. We want the `exposedform_myview_title` to be displayed.

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.iconClick = {
    attach: function(context, setting) {
      $('#someid', context).once().each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function(clickEvent) {
          // Use Ajax to load form.
          $.ajax({
            url: drupalSettings.path.baseUrl + 'views/ajax',
            type: 'GET', // type: 'POST' not succesfull
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'view_name=myview&view_display_id=mypage',
            //not successfull --> data: 'view_name=myview&view_block_id=exposedform_myview',
            success: function(response) {
              var output = response[1].data;
              $('.some-element').html(output);
            },
            error: function(data) {
              alert('error');
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

**page.html.twig**

```
...
<div id="someid">my icon goes here</div>
<div class="some-element"> view block exposed form should go here </div>
...
```

we also tried to use `Drupal.ajax`, but that did not load the View into the required `<div class="some-element">`

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.iconClick = {
    attach: function(context, setting) {
      $('#someid', context).once().each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function(clickEvent) {
          // Use Ajax to load form.
          var ajaxPath = '/views/ajax';
          var view_info = {
            view_name: 'myview',
            view_display_id: 'page'
          };

          var ajax_settings = {
            submit: view_info,
            url: ajaxPath,
            event: 'click'
          };

          Drupal.ajax(ajax_settings);
        });
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the method to POST?

Comment: Even if you manage to get a 200 response, how do you intend to execute the ajax commands in the json data? Try to use `Drupal.ajax` like the Views js library `ajax_view.js` does, then the json will be processed automatically.

Comment: I agree with @4k4

Comment: @4k4 I updated the question with what we tried. I tried using `Drupal.ajax` but that did not insert the view block into the `<div class="some-element">`.

Comment: I've started my last comment with "Even ..." to suggest this is not an easy task. You need to investigate if the endpoint `/views/ajax` provides the information you want and which arguments you have to use to get it. It might be easier to deliver the block in the first page load in a hidden state and show it in javascript.

Comment: @4k4 displaying the block on page load as hidden and showing through JS is the current method we have enabled. We were hoping to optimize the page load by not displaying it at all, but rather on a click event to help improve performance of a page.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post a comment (dumb rule), but did you ever get this figured out? I am able to get a 200 status code for my ajax but my view is not loading in the div. It's been awhile since you posted here. I was wondering if you found a solution.

Comment: @emb03 no i have not been able to resolve this. we ended up loading the block on page load, but used JS to hide and show it when necessary. Still be interested in a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working:

gotchas: 
1. Had to load ajax_view.js, added this code snippet to theme file, check your view source to make sure ajax_view.js is loaded.

```
use \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
function customthemename_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if (isset($view) && ($view->storage->id() == 'community_plan_update_news_feed')) {
    $view->element['#attached']['library'][] = 'pager-view';
  }
}
```

2. Had to write my own jquery once function in Drupal Behaviors file:

```
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
    'use strict';
    // turn off scrolltoTop
    if (Drupal.AjaxCommands) {
        Drupal.AjaxCommands.prototype.viewsScrollTop = null;
    }
    // Write your own jquery once function
    $.fn.once = function(processed_class) {
        if (typeof processed_class == 'undefined') {
            processed_class = 'processed';
        }
        return $(this).not('.' + processed_class).addClass(processed_class);
    };

    Drupal.behaviors.pagerFragments = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            var pager_links = $('.tab-content .pager__items li a').addClass("use-ajax");
        }
    };

    Drupal.behaviors.linkClick = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            $(".pager__items li a", context).on('click', function() {

                var ajaxObject = Drupal.ajax({
                    success: function(response) {
                        var viewHtml = response[1].data;
                        Drupal.settings.views = response[0].settings.views;
                        Drupal.attachBehaviors();
                        if (response[1].data !== undefined) {
                            $('.tab-content').html(viewHtml);
                        }
                        var ajaxPath = 'views/ajax';
                        var view_info = {
                            view_name: 'community_plan_update_news_feed',
                            view_display_id: 'general_plan_news',
                        };
                        var ajax_settings = {
                            submit: view_info,
                            url: ajaxPath,
                            cache: true,
                            event: 'click',
                            async: true,
                        };

                        Drupal.ajax(ajax_settings);
                        ajaxObject.success(response, "success");
                    },

                });
            });
            // reload sharethis icons
            if (__sharethis__ && __sharethis__.config) {
                __sharethis__.init(__sharethis__.config);
            }
            Drupal.behaviors.animate = {
                attach: function(context, settings) {
                    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
                        $('.tab-content').fadeTo(200, 0);
                    });
                    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
                        $('.tab-content').fadeTo(200, 1.0);
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```